# Dashboard shows 2 servers even though workercount is 1

Tags: hangfire

Have a .net core web app that is using hangfire.  Ive set the workercount to one because I dont want a schedule job that is taking longer than normal to get kicked off again until the other finishes.  However, when I look at the dashboard, under "servers" there are two listed.  Are these not the worker threads?  Why are there 2?

Have this in startup

```
app.UseHangfireServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions { WorkerCount = 1 });
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: You always got 2?  On dev machine, if you stop and start your application, it will take times to hangfire dashboard to remove first instance.

Comment: I restarted my app in IIS as well as its app pool, but still have 2 servers, one with 10 workers